# Including a literal backtick in a String.raw template literal

Tags: javascript, template-strings, rawstring

I am working on a system that generates JavaScript, and I would like to minimize the amount of escaping that needs to be done for string literals. My current approach is to use the `String.raw` template literal function so that I don't have to worry characters like `\` being interpreted in the output.

The only issue is that literal backticks (i.e. `` ` `` characters) still need to be escaped, because otherwise they would terminate the string early. They can't be escaped as `` \` `` because escape sequences are not honored.

The best alternative I can think of is to use a placeholder (e.g. `` String.raw`foo${"`"}bar` `` to get `` "foo`bar" ``), but I am somewhat concerned about the runtime cost of the evaluation of placeholders. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: The only alternative i can think of is string concatenation, but to me the one you specified above seems fine